# How to determine the minimum variation of the output of this input

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following [formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tf9jv.png) where the x[n] is an input variable, N the number of variables inserted, 0 < n < N and xrms is the output.

I would like to know how can I understand how the variation of the input variables affects the variation. Like if it is linear or not. For example :

If insert x[n] values 0.351 , 0.352 , 0.353 and then i change them  0.002, like,0.353 , 0.354 and 0.355, i see that the same 0.002 change at the output, so i can assume that is linear but how can i prove this mathematically. Thank you.

Comment: Plot input against output.

Comment: how can i plot a sum of different input values ?

Comment: Rather obvious counterexample: let $N=2$, $x[0] = 0, x[1] = 1$, output is $\sqrt{2} \over 2$. Now add $1$ to every variable, you get $\sqrt{10} \over 2$ which doesn't equal ${\sqrt{2} \over 2} + 1$

Comment: Fair enough, but how can i calculate the variation relationship ?